# Proper way for setting up a Duplex Socket in Unreal Engine

Tags: sockets, tcp, unreal-engine4, bidirectional, duplex

I want to open a TCP socket, connect it to another TCP socket, send there an initialization packet (JSON with a couple of fields), and then listen to the port, from which I have just sent a init packet.

In fact, in some way I need a duplex socket (or more like a bidirectional socket), and as far as I know, this is possible.

Do I understand correctly that I can do this:

1. Initialize FSocket by attaching a specific address + port to it of my server
2. Connect to the desired socket using the FSocket method::Connect(const Internetaddr &Adr) to the “SomeServer” server
3. Send packets using FSocket::SendBytes
4. Start listening to my socket using the FSocket::Listen method, where packets from “SomeServer” will arrive

Will FSocket normally accept that I want to connect first and then listen?

p.s. in the second step, I connect to the “SomeServer” server, after which I should not disconnect from it

Comment: Define 'listen'. In TCP that means a separate socket that is accepting connections. You seem to really mean 'receive' here, in which case you need whatever `recv()` translates to in your API. NB All TCP and UDP sockets are full-duplex. but that means more than just 'bidirectional', which is what you seem to mean here: it means you can send and receive *at the same time.*